# My Python turtle doesn't work when ran in python shell

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am using the Python turtle module and have created the code below:

```
import turtle

def draw_square(some_turtle) :
    some_turtle.forward(100)
    some_turtle.right(90)
    some_turtle.forward(6)
    some_turtle.right(90)
    some_turtle.forward(100)
    some_turtle.left(90)
    some_turtle.forward(6)
    some_turtle.left(90)

def draw_art():
    window = turtle.Screen()
    window.bgcolor("green")
    brad = turtle.Turtle()
    brad.shape("turtle")
    brad.color("red")
    brad.speed(50)
    for i in range(1,10) :
        draw_square(brad)
    window.exitonclick()

draw_art()
```

I want this code to draw a square, but it doesn't. 
Can you explain why this doesn't work? 
problem: I see shell stops working.... ;; can't do more job I want to ... 
          when I click, It doesn't move at all

Comment: No. You haven't posted any code, only a *link* to a *picture* of some code. And you haven't explained what is actually going wrong.

Comment: What goes wrong ? Put your code in the question and the associated output please that we can debug together

Comment: You have syntax errors in `bard.color("red")`, where you have put bard not brad. Also `window.extionclick()` should be `window.exitonclick()`. Both of these errors would have been apparent if you had read the traceback.

Comment: Also, this would draw a rectangle not a square

Answer (score -1):

There are two syntax errors:

`bard.color("red")` should be `brad.color("red")`

`window.extionclick()` should be `window.exitoneclick()`

Correcting those draws a rectangle made of lines going back and forth, if this is what you were trying to do.

Comment: Is this code working??? I can't operate my shell. It stops immediately when I run

Comment: It works when I run it... do you get any feedback from it?

Comment: Typos of that sort are not syntax errors, and also you made a typo yourself (in fact it should be `window.exitonclick()`). Anyway, because the problem was caused by typos, the question should have been closed and not answered.